# How to add one value of JSON to each div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, each

how i can to add one element from JSON to each div? 
(in each div should be other image)

**html**

```
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
```

**script**

```
var i;
    var jsonURL = "img.json";
    $.getJSON(jsonURL, function (json){
        var img= "";
    $.each(json.images, function () {
    for(i=1;i<=2;i++){
        img += '<img src= "' + this.url + '">';
        }
});
    $(".card").append(img);
  });
```

**json**

```
{ "images": [
{"url": "f1.png"},
{"url": "f2.png"},
{"url": "f3.png"} ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I assumed that you want to add images, div by div. That can be done by `eq()` as shown below.

```
$.each(json.images, function (key, value) {
   $(".card").eq(key).append('<img src= "' + value.url + '">');    
});
```

```js
var json = { "images": [
{"url": "f1.png"},
{"url": "f2.png"},
{"url": "f3.png"} ]};

$.each(json.images, function (key, value) {
        $(".card")
          .eq(key)
          .append('<img src= "' + value.url + '">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: The better way is using `.append( function )` instead of `.each()` that doesn't need to `.eq()` and additional dom search.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each class and get the image url with the index.

```js
var json = { "images": [
{"url": "f1.png"},
{"url": "f2.png"},
{"url": "f3.png"} ]};
    $('.card').each(function (i, v) {
       var img = '<img src= "' + json.images[i].url + '">';
        $(v).append(img)
       
        }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">1</div>
<div class="card">2</div>
<div class="card">3</div>
```